# Text over an image in an rdlc in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, background-image, reportviewer, rdlc

In VS2010, I've created an rdlc report that I want to view using the reportviewer. On the report, I want to use a scanned image underneath all the text (since it must look like the agency's letterhead), and this image must take up the whole page. The problem is that the text boxes on the report are all bumped down beneath the image. Can someone help me figure out how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Right click the image, select Layout, Send to Back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this in VS 2012 now, but I think it's the same in VS 2010.
Right click the body of your report (in design mode),
Select "Body Properties..." and from there you can specify a Background Image.

Answer (score 0):

You can place text above the image at design time. When ReportViewer display the report, it will look bad, but if you export the report in PDF format will look the same as you wish.

I know my answer does not resolve the problem. After working a lot on the subject, it is all I could get.

I have now tried in VS2013. No change.